# regex for n characters or at least z characters

Tags: .net, regex

I have a input control (.net Regex and must be 1 liner) that I have to make sure it's either 15 characters long with - .  or input box can have N/A

for example, 1443-RXSW3-8738   -  this is 15 characters long
or  N/A

So far I have this `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{15}$‍‍`    and this only makes sure it has at least 15 character.

Is it possible to have a 1 line Regex for this? The following works. I just have to make sure if it's 15 characters long then it must have hyphen.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{15}$‍‍|(N\/A\b)
```

Input box must have 15 characters long and must have -.  or it can have N

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `^([a-zA-Z0-9-]{15}|N/A)$`.  We simply add hyphen to the character class at either the end or the start to ensure it is treated as a normal character.

Try it out at http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%5ba-zA-Z0-9-%5d%7b15%7d%7cN%2fA%29%24&i=1443-RXSW3-8738

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#positive-character-group--